# outOfMemoryError on J2ME application

Tags: memory, java-me, lwuit, heap-memory

recently I'm developing a `J2ME` application using `LWUIT` library, my application size is `679 KB` after obfusticating.
in some mobile devices and in non-specific events I get `OutOfMemoryError` error.

I want to know what this error is for and does it related to Memory of device or its a bug of my application, and what is the solution?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It means (duh!!) you're out of memory.  Generally this means out of heap memory (which is limited by a JVM parameter), but on rare occasions you can run out of other pools.  Most likely the application created more objects than will fit in allotted memory.

Comment: tanx Hot Licks for this anwer , actually my application works for both touch screen and non touch screen devices in 2 languages , therefor i had to use lots of icons and images in themes and resources,
I have to reduce size of these objects if i dnt find any other way to get rid of this error :(

Comment: First thing to do is to check the docs for your environment and figure out how to adjust the heap size.  Unfortunately, the way to do this is somewhat non-standard, but it's generally done with the `-Xmx` parameter on the `java` command.

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390087/javame-lwuit-images-eat-up-all-the-memory

Comment: are you using photos or audio/video file in your project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to tell how to fix your application without studying it. [This wiki entry](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_Memory_Management) is a good start to understand what to look for when optimizing memory for JavaME apps.

Comment: tanx Gorkem , i will check it